# Can "forcibly" be used in an action that a person performs to himself/herself?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

For example, can I say:

> She doesn't cry very loud. When she cries it sounds like a string of almost inaudible sobs she **forcibly** wants hold inside.

Can forcibly be used in a case like the one presented above? If not, what's a better verb to use?

Comment: ... sobs she *bottles up* inside.

Comment: Or sobs she *stifles.*

Comment: Yes, *stifles* is better.

Comment: Off-topic - asking for writing advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for writing advice and would be better asked on [writers.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "forcibly" is correct in the context you provided.  In the context you provided, an individual is working to assert her will over an involuntary response.  One can do this "forcibly," but it sounds odd when the adverb "forcibly" is used as a modifier for the verb "want."  If you forcibly want something, does that mean you actually *don't* want it?

I think the sentence would be improved by removing either "forcibly" or "want."  "When she cries it sounds like a string of almost inaudible sobs she forcibly holds inside."  OR  "... inaudible sobs she wants to hold inside."  Even better in my opinion would be to replace "wants" with "struggles." "... inaudible sobs she struggles to hold inside."

[Struggle](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/struggle) - strive to achieve or attain something in the face of difficulty or resistance